# How can I set three UserControls to display in a TabItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have done some google searches on the subject and I think either I must be doing something so basic it doesn't require an answer or I'm trying to solve my problem in a complicated way and need to rethink the whole thing.

I have a factory object that creates a Window - this is called by a command within a separate ViewModel object.  The factory object is responsible for assigning the datacontext to the list of data passed through to it.  The list can be of variable count and each item within the list should display on a separate tab on the TabControl of the Window.

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=VMNameAndDate, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I'm currently using ItemContainerStyle to set the TabItem header.
This works for the header but I need to have three separate UserControls to display on each of the TabItems.
I've added the namespace for the UserControls to Window

```
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ThisProgram.UserControls"
```

I have tried to set them as resources without success.  As you probably have gathered I'm very new to WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a lot of digging and a final reconciliation with Templates within WPF the answer was:

```
            <TabControl Name="ViewModeListTabControl" Grid.Column="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedViewModel,
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource UCAnother}">
        <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="UCAnother"  DataType="{x:Type my:AnotherUserControl}" >
                    <my:AnotherUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"></my:AnotherUserControl>
                </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
```

I needed to set the ContentTemplate of the TabControl to a master UserControl that held the other UserControls. I had to reference the master UserControl within a DataTemplate in the TabControl's resources.
This is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

if the following is your namespace

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ThisProgram.UserControls"
```

then

```
<Grid>
        <TabControl>           
            <TabItem Header="UC1" >
                <my:ucSDH ></my:ucSDH>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="UC2">
                <my:ucWDH ></my:ucWDH>
            </TabItem>

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

You can append DataContext to the UserControls as needed

If you want to bind itemsSource to TabControl then:

```
public ObservableCollection<Object> coll { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    coll = new ObservableCollection<Object>();

    Object uc1 = new UserControl1();
    Object uc2 = new UserControl2();
    coll.Add(uc1);
    coll.Add(uc2);

    tab1.ItemsSource = coll;
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tab1" ItemsSource="{Binding coll}"></TabControl>
```

Comment: Tnanks for the response but unfortunately I cannot use this as it would mean that the ItemSource would need to be empty.  The list of objects is assigned in the TabControl ItemSource

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can now set the TabItems using ItemsSource property of TabControl

Comment: Again thanks for the answer but I then lose my ViewModel objects which ideally should be the ItemSource.  I'm really trying to set up a template type holder and make it my usercontrols part of the template.  I'm only using them to display data not be the data if you understand me.

Comment: I did not get you. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to display my viewmodel object on a TabItem that contains some UserControls. The tabitems are not preset.

Comment: So you can do it in the above way mentioned. Instead of creating a new collection I suppose you already have a collection from the ViewModel,so just Bind it to the TabControl's ItemsSource and it should work fine. Is it showing any error? Please post your ViewModel

Comment: I think that I'm getting confused now.  I'm not sure how to reference the UserControl within the XAML.  My list of objects have nothing to do directly with the UserControl, my itemSource is already assigned to an ObservableCollection of my viewmodel objects.  I just don't know how to reference the UserControls on the associated TabItems that the TabControl generates when it's ItemSource is rendered.  Please bear in mind that the list could contain no objects at all.